# Как дозаписывать данные в таблицу в postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datatable

Как автоматически в postgres дописывать данные в таблицу? У меня данные, которые должны обновляться и дописываться каждый день, то есть как дописывать в таблицу каждый новый день?

Сейчас я использую код вида:

```
CREATE table Table X;
INSERT into Table X

Select *
from A
```

Этот код не дозаписывает мне каждый новый день(

Comment: Логично, вы же сначала удаляете все записи из таблицы, а потом записываете новые. Зачем вы так делаете?

Comment: Вы понимаете смысл - `truncate`?

Comment: А зачем каждый день создавать таблицу. ее надо создать один раз и в последующем делать только insert. А дальнейшее уже зависит исключительно от ваших данных. Например что находится в таблице "A", как эти данные соотносятся с теми данными, что же есть в таблице "X" и что собственно обозначает "дозаписать", это создать абсолютно новые строки или может часть строк надо модифицировать, так как они уже есть. В общем на ваш вопрос не возможно ответить, так как не хватает конкретики

Answer (score 1):

В PostgreSQL нет job, как в Oracle. Средствами самого PostgreSQL нельзя периодически выполнять задачу. Нужно использовать внешние инструменты: cron, PgAgent, расширение pg_cron или делать периодический вызов внутри своей программы.

Пример периодического выполнения функции на Node.js:

```
function doDBJob() {
  executeSQL("INSERT INTO films VALUES
    ('UA502', 'Bananas', 105, '1971-07-13', 'Comedy', '82 minutes');")
}
setInterval(doDBJob, 24*60*60*1000);
```

или с помощью модуля node-schedule:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const EVERY_MIDNIGHT = '0 0 * * *';
schedule.scheduleJob(EVERY_MIDNIGHT, () => {
  executeSQL("INSERT INTO films VALUES
    ('UA502', 'Bananas', 105, '1971-07-13', 'Comedy', '82 minutes');")
}
```

Похожий вопрос: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43937/how-to-run-recurring-tasks-on-a-postgresql-database-without-a-cron-like-tool

CREATE table Table X; конечно, нужно делать только один раз